# Prepend zeros to int java

Tags: java, string

I want to prepend zeros to an int if its string equivalent length is less than 6. Similar to String.format. Example:

```
int e = 21;
System.out.println(String.format("%06d", e)); //000021
int e = 3564;
System.out.println(String.format("%06d", e)); //003564
```

What I need is for the above inputs `210000` and `356400` the zeros prepended at the end. Is there something already implemented which will do the job or do i need to code it by my self? If so how to deal with variable length?

Comment: `while (e < 100_000) e *= 10;` ?

Comment: @SilviuBurcea shame on me. :-)

Comment: Use padding. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#rightPad(java.lang.String,%20int,%20char)

Comment: Also, you don't have to call `String.format()`.  You can use `System.out.printf()` when printing formatted values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (e < 100_000) e *= 10;
```

Self-explanatory. I don't think there is an easier way than that.

Edit:
Since `e` can be 0, I'd wrap the above statement into a function:

```
public static String pad(int input) {
  if (input == 0) return "000000";
  while (input < 100_000) input *= 10;
  return "" + input;
}
```

Comment: What do you do if `e` is `0`? :)

Comment: Thank you very much. This easy solution haven't come to my mind. Will accept the answer when the ten minutes are over.

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer edited to handle 0 as well.

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer good point but irrelevant for my context as my inputs are always > 0.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea it also doesn't handle negative numbers.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know, but I assumed that negative numbers are not valid for the problem that's being solved. I only focused to provide a working solution for OP's problem, not handle every possible case. One would be able to derive a solution for negative numbers having my answer's root idea, if that is needed.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea one would have been able to derive how to handle zero too :)

Answer (score 4):

If wanted to do something like [what Dimitri suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56044296/3788176), but you don't want to depend on an external library, you write a little method:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(6);
sb.append(e);
sb.append("000000", Math.min(sb.length(), 6), 6);
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html), you have access to the `rightPad` method :

```
StringUtils.rightPad(String.valueOf(e), 6, "0");
```

Comment: Note: That is a third party class.  Not part of the Java API.

Answer (score 1):

The following method pads the supplied string, with the supplied character, until the field width is reached.

```java
   public static String rightPad(String str, int fieldwidth, char c) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
      while (fieldwidth > sb.length()) {
         sb.append(c);
      }
      return sb.toString();
   }
```

Example:  To pad 1234 with two zeros, do the following:

```java
int v = 1234;
String padded = rightPad(Integer.toString(v), 6, '0');
```